# Pass ajax value to a variable in node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have an ajax get request that has a data of an input. I want to pass this data into a variable and use it in my query.

index.handlebars

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" class="test" name="test" value="sample"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var username = $('.test').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url: '/users//welcome',
                    data : {
                        wew: username
                    }
                });
                alert(username); //correct output
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in my users/welcome

```
router.get('/welcome', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){

    var test = req.query.wew; //data from ajax request

    Item.find({username: test},function(err, docs, test){    
        //where username is the data
        console.log(test);
        res.render('welcome', {docs:docs});
    });
});
```

This code is not working. Please help :/

Comment: "the code is not working" is very broad - can you explain what your problem is

Comment: I want to store the ajax data to a variable in server.js. The second set of codes is my server

Comment: so you need to send data from browser to server?

Comment: exactly! is please give some codes

Comment: does it work if you use the exact URL in the url parameter for example http://localhost/welcome

Comment: do you have any error logs you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io).    I use it for bi-directional communication between the browser and node.js server.

On the client side you would do:

```
function movePlayer () {
    socket.emit ('doSomethingServerSide', {numVal: 4, usrName: 'KaiserSolze'});
}
```

And server side you would have:

```
//  A FUNCTION THAT LISTENS FOR A CALL FROM BROWSERS CONNECTED VIA SOCKET
 socket.on ('doSomethingServerSide', function (msg) {
   // THEN YOU COULD REPORT TO ALL BROWSERS / CLIENTS THAT SOMETHING WAS DONE
   io.sockets.emit ('reportToClients', msg);
 });
```

If you decide to go this route there are lots of posts here to help you get started with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your website full URL with http and replace double (//)  with one

```
  $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        url: 'http://<your application full url>/users/welcome',
                        data : {
                            wew: username
                        }
                    });
```

Or you can try below

```
$.ajax({
           url: "/users/welcome?wew="+username,
           type: "GET",
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = req.query.wew; //data from ajax request
```

Just change to this one with this one:

```
var test = req.body.wew
```

Also you need to import body parser to your project for getting `req.body.keynames`